# Only run context preprocessor for views from my app

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings

In my django app ("`pm`"), I have a template context processor that adds a number of variables to every view:

```
def menu_items(request):
    return {
        'projects': Project.objects.all().order_by('name'),
        'people': People.objects.filter(Q(group="MAAD") | Q(group="OAR")).order_by('name')
    }
```

The problem is, my app is just one of many running on our django project/instance/server/whatever. Since this is added to the `TEMPLTATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR` constant, it will be executed every time *any* app's view runs. I want to ensure that this only runs when the views from *my* app are called, so as to avoid adding overhead to views from other apps. **How can I verify that the view being called is from my app?** In case it helps, I do have namespacing set up for my app:

```
url(r'^pm/', include('pm.urls', namespace="pm")),
```

...but I couldn't figure out a way to check the namespace of a view on the fly. Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 1.5, a `ResolverMatch` object is stored on `request.resolver_match`, which contains a list of namespaces of the current url:

```
def menu_items(request):
    if 'pm' in request.resolver_match.namespaces:
        return {
            'projects': Project.objects.all().order_by('name'),
            'people': People.objects.filter(Q(group="MAAD") | Q(group="OAR")).order_by('name')
        }
    return {}
```